# Copy file recursively to all deepest subdirectories

Tags: find, directory, cp

I'm trying to copy a single file to all of the deepest subdirectories in a tree structure. Imagine it looks like this:

```
bar
dir1
 |  |
 |  +--dir2
 |    |
 |    +--dir3
 |  +--dir4
 |    |
 |    +--dir5
 |  +--dir6
 |    |
 |    +--dir7
```

I want "bar" to be copied only to the deepest subdirectories, like this:

```
bar
dir1
 | +--dir2
 |   |
 |    +--dir3
 |     | 
 |     +-- bar
 | +--dir4
 |   |
 |   +--dir5
 |     | 
 |     +-- bar
 | +--dir6
 |   |
 |   +--dir7
 |     | 
 |     +-- bar
```

I'm not sure how to approach this, since files end up in middle directories sometimes, but I can't find a way to target the deepest subdirectories.

Edit: my attempt at solving this. This copies to all directories inconsistently, still for some reason, not just the deepest ones.

```
find . -exec cp -r bar {} \; -type d -links 2
```

Comment: Please add your attempt, even if failed. Have a look at <https://stackoverflow.com/a/27629943>, you will be able to easily answer your own question with that and the `-exec` option of find :)

Comment: Added, thanks that link helped.

Comment: @bactro check the command you typed in the question, seems wrong.

Comment: Yes thanks! Appreciate it.

Comment: Do you really need a distinct copy of the original file in each directory? Would hard-linking to the reference copy be better?

Comment: Hi @Paul_Pedant, my question was answered. But I'm interested in your point, mind explaining? I'm running an executable in each subfolder, so I think having separate copies is best.

Comment: It depends on whether you want an identical file in each directory (maybe a standard config or script), or whether it gets modified differently in each directory (maybe stores usage stats). If it is a standard file that might need updating, then you would need to update all of them. However ... a file consists of a directory entry (just name and a "number"), and a disc area called an inode which is identified by the number and holds all the data blocks, permissions, timestamps etc. Linux allows "hard links" which lets many dir entries point to the same inode. So only one copy of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
find . -type d -links 2 -exec cp  file  {} \;
```

It will find directories having 2 hard links, and then copy your file to that particular directory.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: On the directory containing `bar`,

```
find . -type d -links 2 -exec cp bar {} \;
```

---

Your original attempt

```
find . -exec cp -r bar {} \; -type d -links 2
```

contains no syntactic errors, but does not behave as you expected. Because `-exec` comes before the `-type` and `-links` filters, the filters never apply and `exec` gets everything under (and including) the current directory, not only regular files but also directories. If you are not convinced, check the output of

```
find . -exec echo X{}X \; -type d -links 2 -exec echo Y{}Y \;
```

You will see that all the files get listed between two `X`, but only only the correct `dir{3,5,7}` files between two `Y`. That explains why `bar` popped up in middle directories too.

Also, the `-r` option activates recursive copies. Since what is being copied is a regular file (`bar`), `-r` is not needed.